How might you quantise this non-polynomial action?
I am interested in the following non-polynomial action:
$$L = \sqrt{(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi^2 + m^2 \phi^2 -\lambda^2\phi^4)^2  + \varepsilon^2 } dx^2 $$
where $\varepsilon$ is very small. So in other words, classically, at large scales it should behave like a $\phi^4$ theory. (Actually the Lagrangian would be the absolute value of this.)
So, the first instinct is to say that the Feynman rules should be very similar to $\phi^4$ with a small perturbation caused by $\varepsilon$.
But, when we try to expand out this Lagrangian into a polynomial form so we can calculate the Feynman rules we find it expands in powers of $1/\varepsilon$ which is a huge number.
$$L \propto \varepsilon^2 + (\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi^2 + m^2 \phi^2 -\lambda^2\phi^4)^2 + O(\varepsilon^{-1})$$
Since $\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon^2} = \varepsilon\sqrt{a^2/\varepsilon^2 + 1} = \varepsilon + \frac{1}{2}a^2 \varepsilon^{-1} + O(\varepsilon^{-1})$
The series would not converge until about $1/\varepsilon$ terms which is very bad for Feynman rules. Is there any way out of this situation or is it hopeless to try and use Feynman diagrams for this situation?
So thus this seemingly small modification seems to mess being able to use Feynman rules.

You expanded the series wrong. You need to drag out a

Hi bob. 1. Which Minkowski signature convention do you use? 2. What is the motivation behind the non-polynomial action?

@Confuse-ray30 Unfortunately you can't do that otherwise you get a series in inverse powers of a which is also non-polynomial which is no good for Feynman rules.

You are correct. But is this a formal series you are trying to do? Since the radius of convergence is not infinity for square root. So the other expansion "has nothing to do with the original lagrangian"

whether its good for Feynman rules or not is irrelevant here. Your Taylor expansion is simply incorrect. You must pull out $a$, not $\varepsilon$, as @Confuse-ray30 mentioned.

When you expand $\sqrt{1+(a/\epsilon)^2}$ into low order, you are implicitly assuming $a$ is small or $\epsilon$ is large. What you should do is expand $\sqrt{1+(\epsilon/a)^2}$.

How to quantize the theory?  I see no obvious problem defining functional integral quantization if you provide a UV cutoff.  How to cook up a scheme that has familiar particle states and Feynman rules for pertubative expansion?  Beats me.
